# Basic Arrays in a Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a beginner in Java and am working on a basic program that includes arrays and loops. The program must:
- ask the user to enter the name of a 'salesman' 5 times. These 5 names will be stored into a String array.
- another DOUBLE array is used to store the amount of sales each person has made.
- the data will be printed in the end.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String[] names = new String[5];
    System.out.println ("What is the name of the person?")
    String name = scan.next();

    double[] sales = new double[5];
    sales[0] = 15000.00;
    sales[1] = 10000.00;
    sales[2] = 4500.00;
    sales[3] = 2500.00;
    sales[4] = 3500.00;

    System.out.println(name1 + "sold " + sales[0]);
    System.out.println(name2 + "sold " + sales[1]);
    System.out.println(name3 + "sold " + sales[2]);
    System.out.println(name4 + "sold " + sales[3]);
    System.out.println(name5 + "sold " + sales[4]);
    }
}
```

I know the first part is incorrect... as well as most of the output.

My instructor is not very interested in explaining much to our class. She is usually too busy working with a different part of the class. I basically know nothing about arrays.
I will certainly learn something if one of you is kind enough to tell me what I need to enter and where?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html -- Do you have another question?

Comment: You will need to construct a loop, that executes 5 times. Each time in that loop, you need to increment a counter variable starting at 0. Use that value to specify the index of the array names[] to store the value read in from console. Then you will print out the values referencing the same index in both the names[] array and the sales[] array :D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use for loops to avoid having to repeat the lines of code for each instance. You want something more like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String[] names = new String[5];
    double[] sales = new double[5];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
         System.out.println ("What is the name of the person?");
         name[i] = scan.next();
         System.out.println ("How much did they sell?");
         sales[i] = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {        
        System.out.println (name[i] + " sold " + sales[i]);
    }
}
```

look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html for more on how to use the for loop.  The loops that I wrote will execute the code inside when i=0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.  `i=0` tells the loop where to begin.  `i<5` tells the loop to execute the code inside as long as i is less than 5.  And `i++` is shorthand for `i=i+1` and tells the loop what to do to i at the end (increase i by 1 and test the end condition again).

ETA: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html shows how to use the Scanner class to get input.

Comment: If you don't understand what I did, please ask me.  Don't just copy the code and hand it in without understanding it, or you're going to get more and more lost as the course goes on!

Comment: You need to use nextLine instead of next and also call nextLine after nextDouble. If you don't advance the Scanner you will get an InputMismatchException.

Comment: I just tested a simple set of scans, and I do not seem to need the nextLine calls at all.

Comment: Thanks so much! Got the program to work in class today thanks to you. I just had to switch the second 'int i' to 'int j' so it will work properly. Thanks also to everyone else for the quick help! :)

Comment: You shouldn't have had to switch to j, because the loops are separate.  The first loop is completely terminated before the second one starts, so you can use the same loop variable.  You obviously need to use separate variables when doing nested loops.  Good luck with the rest of your class!

Answer (score 5):

It will be easier when you use collections.

Use this for simple implementation and better understanding for collections.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

For printing use this.

```
for(String result : list){
System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: This is for a programming class where they're learning about arrays, according to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Scanner inside a loop.

```
    String[] names = new String[5];
double[] sales = new double[5];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.print ("Please input name of sale " + (i+1) + ": ");
    names[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Please input sales of sale " + (i+1) + ": ");
    sales[i] = scanner.nextDouble();

}
// following lines is for testing
for(int i=0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.println(names[i]+" " + sales[i]);
}
```

Since Java is a Object oriented, so I recommend you to create a class named Salesman containing name and sale attributes.

```
// Salesman class
class Salesman{
    private String name;
    private double sales;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(double sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }
}
```

And once again the main method.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    List<Salesman> salesmanList = new ArrayList<Salesman>(5);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        Salesman salesman = new Salesman();
        System.out.print ("Please input name of sale " + (i+1) + ": ");
        salesman.setName(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print ("Please input sales of sale " + (i+1) + ": ");
        salesman.setSales(scanner.nextDouble());
        salesmanList.add(salesman);

    }
    // following lines is for testing
    for(Salesman salesman : salesmanList){
        System.out.println(salesman.getName()+" " + salesman.getSales());
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use nextLine instead of next and also call nextLine after nextDouble. If you don't advance the Scanner you will get an InputMismatchException.

Comment: I'm confused by the `(i+1)`'s. Why not just `i` and start at 1? Also why not have a constructor for the `Salesman` class? That way you can set their fields upon instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void getInput(){ 

 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


 System.out.println("Enter the total no of i/p :")

 int count = scanner.nextInt();

    List<String> collectionOfInput = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        collectionOfInput.add(scanner.nextLine());

    }
    }
     public void printOutput(){

     for(String outputValue : collectionOfInput){

            System.out.println(result);
        }
```